# How do I define a many-to-many relationship that specifies a relationship type?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, relational-database

I am using Hibernate and MySql (old versions of both - Seam 2 project).

I am having trouble figuring out how to set up my mapping table and the entity annotations so that I can "color" the types of relationships between two entities (as if I were coloring edges on a graph).  Here's an approximation of my schema:

**customer**

- id
- fullName
- phoneNumber

**store**

- id
- branchName
- addressFirstLine
- addressSecondLine

**customer_store**

- customer_id
- store_id
- customertype

**customertype**

- value (enumerated: individual, corporate, internal)

### What is the best approach for designing my Hibernate annotations and schema to properly map these relationships?

Approaches I've looked at:

1. I feel like I could have three `Set<Store>` properties on the `Customer` object, one for each `CustomerType`, or a single `Set<Store> getStores(CustomerType)` method.  I don't know how to make this mapping though, and I'm having a hard time finding docs for this specific scenarios.
2. I could change my schema to have a table per `customertype` (`customer_store_individual`, `customer_store_corporate`, etc).  This feels redundant, but it would solve the problem.  I'd prefer to let hibernate do some magic to sort out this mapping and combine these to one table, though.
3. I could make an entity for the `customer_store` table.  This feels like a really gross work-around.  [This answer already covers this type of relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574975/how-to-implement-a-3-many-to-many-relationship-with-hibernate), though I don't like this solution.

Note that I'm trying to obfuscate my domain, so please avoid making suggestions about the customer or store objects themselves.  Lets assume that my domain objects are factored correctly, and that they are truly a many-to-many relationship.  It is just distinguishing the type of each link that I am having trouble with :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it is the best solution but i would go with a value object for the relation

```
@Entity
public class Customer
{
    // to get all stores
    @ElementCollection
    public Set<StoreCustomer> stores;

    // to get specific stores
    public Set<Store> getStores(CustomerType);
}

@Entity
public class Store
{
    // to get all customers
    @ElementCollection
    public Set<StoreCustomer> customers;

    // to get specific customers
    public Set<Customer> getCustomers(CustomerType);
}

@Embeddable
public class StoreCustomer
{
    @ManyToOne
    public Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    public Store store;

    public CustomerType type;
}
```

Comment: How would I implement each of these?  Would the `Customer.getStores` and `Store.getCustomers` methods be custom transient methods, or is there a way to get hibernate to automatically map them for me?

Comment: both is possible. custom method which filters all stores/customers or readonly collections mapped as manytomany with sqlwhere condition on the customertype column